# create a spring MVC with JQueryMobile

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have to create an web application, using Spring MVC and Hibernate.
 But the condition is web application should be accessible on all smart phone(iPhone, Android, tablet as well as Desktop).

If I am using phones it means some less information will be displayed and if I am using Desktop full site will be displayed. It means I need to created two kinds of pages for all views.

I was referring JQuery Mobile, but not sure how far i can go with these selection.

and If I render the same HTML for all devices and Desktop. please give your opinion on this also.

Please guide me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides one separate framework to achieve mobile web app.
Please check this [link](http://www.springsource.org/spring-mobile) for more details about that.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes Thanks,according to that I need to create page for each device. it means same page i need to recreate more than one times. is it?

Comment: I don't know much about it in detail. But I just know that with help of this framework you can build mobile web app. :-)